# gnu make - seek example of where directory time would influence out-of-date

Tags: make, gnu

The GNU make manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rules) '4.3 Types of Prerequisites' says of order-only-prerequisites

> Consider an example where your targets are to be placed in a separate
> directory, and that directory might not exist before make is run. In
> this situation, you want the directory to be created before any
> targets are placed into it but, because the timestamps on directories
> change whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed, we certainly
> don’t want to rebuild all the targets whenever the directory’s
> timestamp changes. One way to manage this is with order-only
> prerequisites:

Why would the directory time ever influence out-of-date?

Comment: Read `man touch`, and you can do your own research.

Comment: @waltinator I'm aware of touch and currently experimenting with it albeit on a different make subject. What i don't understand is if make is checking to see if the .c file is older than the .o file what has the directory timestamp got to do with it?